# Pipe a .BIN file into XModem transfer

Tags: pipe, file-transfer

I need to send a `.bin` file to a modem via `XModem` transfer for firmware upgrading.

If the modem is connected to a local computer, the command would be the following:

```
sz -X -k -b -vvv - file_to_transfer.BIN > /dev/ttyUSB0 < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I've also made the commands required on the module side to receive the file.

The problem is that I need to do this on a remote host that has these modems inside them. I cannot transfer the file to the device, because the host doesn't have enough memory to store the file.

The idea in the end is to pipe the file into the `sz` command. I tried this locally with the command:

```
cat file_to_transfer.BIN | sz -X -k -b -vvv - > /dev/ttyUSB0 < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This command gives the following error message:

```
Sending s2382.lsz, 0 blocks: Give your local XMODEM receive command now.
Xmodem sectors/kbytes sent:   0/ 0kRetry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Timeout on sector ACK

Retry 0: Retry Count Exceeded
```

Could someone please explain why this isn't working or if there is a better idea to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you read from *and* write to `/dev/ttyUSB0`? I'm no XModem expert, but I'd expect the following to work from your local system: `cat file_to_transfer.BIN | sz -X -k -b -vvv - > /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: @mjturner that won't work. XModem (or ZModem) is a bidirectional protocol. Here when `sz` wants to send things to the remote side it will write to its stdout which is the serial port which is fine, but when it reads responses back it will read them from its stdin which is the pipe to `cat` which is... wrong.

Comment: How do you connect to the remote host? `ssh`? I suspect that your solution will involve running `sx` locally where the file is available, connected to some sort of socket or coprocess that gives it access to the remote serial port. Another possible solution could be to mount the file over the network: `sshfs`, or NFS.

Answer (score 3):

A little late I suppose, but I just ran into a similar problem.

Use a fifo (named pipe). See https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo

```
# Create a temporary fifo
mkfifo /tmp/sz_fifo

# Write the file to the fifo and place in the background
# (Replace "cat" with some other command to stream over the network)
cat file_to_transfer.BIN > /tmp/sz_fifo &

# sz will read the file from the fifo
sz -X -k -b -vvv - /tmp/sz_fifo > /dev/ttyUSB0 < /dev/ttyUSB0

# Clean up
rm /tmp/sz_fifo
```